# Can't see computers in workgroup, but pinging works

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, home-networking, windows-networking

I have a problem with configuration my home network.
I using Windows 7, Windows XP and Dlink DIR-300 for create home network. I ping all of my computer and ping works, but I don't see computer in working group.

So the work group also named as "HOME" for both computers, and shared folders exist on both computers too.

Have you got the same problem? I need to exchange some data from computer where installed Windows XP.

I used this tutorial but it does not help me. [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/)

Comment: Go to the My Computer Properties and check if you have the same Group setup on both computers. Additionally File sharing is enabled on WIndows 7 only if you choose that current network connection is Home type and not Public. This you can change in the Network Sharing in Control Panel. Please check it.

Comment: thanks for response, yes I have checked it. My connection is home type. and name of group is the same.

Comment: WHat do you see when you access the \\WIN7HOSTNAME and \\WINXPHOSTNAME ? Try to access it both locally and from the other computer.

Comment: You can also check by using the command `nbtstat -A 192.168.0.1` where 192.168.0.1 is the IP of the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open 445 TCP port on Windows XP machine, or try to turn off firewall at all. This port are used for SMB protocol, through which Windows gain access for network shares.

Answer (score 0):

in windows XP try disabling the antivirus in the computer to enable these computer to share resources while in windows 7, enable the share printer and folder radio button to enable the two computers to share resources